# Python: zipping tuple of numbers and lists of strings

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got a list of lists and a tuple. I'm trying to zip them into a list of lists with three "columns".  Here's what I have:

```
splitKeys=[['259', ' 46'], ['281', ' 71'], ['49', ' 13378']]
data=(2.2217806892532197, 1.1757204348143286, 0.55)
b=zip(splitKeys, data)
```

but, I get this:

```
[(['259', ' 46'], 2.2217806892532197), (['281', ' 71'], 1.1757204348143286), 
(['49', '13378'], 0.55)]
```

when I really want this:

```
[('259', ' 46', 2.2217806892532197), ('281', ' 71', 1.1757204348143286),
 ('49', '13378], 0.55)]
```

I've tried a few different methods, using both `map` and `lambda`, but am still getting the undesirable output I noted above.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
b = [(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in zip(splitKeys, data)]
```

Comment: oooh thats nice lookin

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily unpack the lists before zipping with generator expressions:

```
b = zip((k[0] for k in splitKeys), (k[1] for k in splitKeys), data)
```

Output:

```
b
Out[4]: 
[('259', ' 46', 2.2217806892532197),
 ('281', ' 71', 1.1757204348143286),
 ('49', ' 13378', 0.55)]
```

Comment: Considering this works I wouldn't have downvoted it...regardless of the extra iteration over `splitKeys`. Explanation please?